# express-session: check if another session with same session.username exists

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I included express-session in my node.js project to establish sessions. 
My goal is:

**Every username should only be available once within the system**

My current approach how to do this:

With each login I create a new session and store the username variable inside this session. I also push the username to an array that holds all Strings of all logged in users.

The problem is: If I close the browser in incognito mode, the session is gone but my user array still contains the outdated username. Thus (if the user reloads the page and wants to login again) he cannot do that because his username is still within the username array.

So: 
I want to get rid of the array and instead I would like to check all existing sessions if the desired username is stored within any of their userName-variables.

Is there a way to check all existing sessions for a certain session variable?